# Body kit attached with some kind of rubbery adhesive. Anyway to detach it safely?

Tags: vw, golf, body-work

My Mk1 Golf Cabriolet has a factory fitted body kit (the 'Clipper' kit). There are some scratches on one of the wheel arches and I thought it would be easier to remove them to re-paint but there seems to be some gummy black adhesive holding them firmly in place. I am worried that if I pull the arches off they will break or the paint will peel.

Does anyone know the best way remove this safely and what this adhesive is called so I can buy more when I need to replace it?

Comment: For badges and the like "sawing" them off with dental floss works pretty well. You stretch the floss like you were doing your teeth and run it back and forth between the badge and the bodywork.

Comment: @dlu hey that's a really good idea! I might put it into practice with my badges (last owner stuck a GTI badge on it :| )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an article on VW Vortex on [removing a Clipper kit](http://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?1592430-Removing-a-clipper-kit-what-do-I-need), it sounds like there are rivets which have to be drilled out as well as some mechanical fasteners *and* the tape.

The Bentley manual has the instructions for installing the kit which may be helpful to you as well.